# mapbox-gl - how to instantiate a Map for a simple test

Tags: unit-testing, mapbox-gl-js

I'd like to start by asking Mapbox - please - to put documentation on their site that explains how to set up and start doing a simple test. There are many tests in their code on Github, but after days of reading and attempting to test I have failed to understand how they work.

I have a very simple method that:

1. updates some geoJson with some new coordinates and a new heading (rotation) for a marker.
2. uses setSource to set the changed Json to the Map

I would like to run my little method in a test and then check that the new coordinates have arrived in the Map.

- Should be a piece of cake!

Now a `Map` needs a browser or similar. Yes, there's `jsdom`, which is almost certainly what is needed, but I have not discovered how you give the dom to the Map.

If I try to instantiate either `window`, which I found in mapbox-js utils, or `Map`, I get

**ReferenceError: self is not defined**. - 'self' appears to be the window object.

I use mocha, with babel 7, for what it's worth, but I think that all I need is to solve the mystery of setting up a Map instance so that I can then interrogate it.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Did you ever discover a solution for this?